# How to open a list of PRs automatically in Github?

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions, github-api

We have a repo (SaaS project) that contains a list of branches (50-100), the master branch is up to date, So I want to open a list of PRs for every branch we have to take updates from

`master -> client-*`

So is there a way to handle this case automatically?

Comment: Hi Oliver,
I assume that with github API you can do that automatically

Comment: @FrédéricLang yeah I see, do you have an idea how to do it? What I thought is to grab all branches of client-* in array and loop for sending a POST to create those PRs 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Github's API to fetch all of your branches and to publish PRs.  Unfortunately, Github doesn't provide a method for filtering when listing branches, so you will still need to apply that filter in your own code.

Here's an example execution using [Octokit](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/libraries).  The two methods needed are [repos.listBranches](https://github.com/octokit/plugin-rest-endpoint-methods.js/blob/master/docs/repos/listBranches.md) and [pulls.create](https://github.com/octokit/plugin-rest-endpoint-methods.js/blob/master/docs/pulls/create.md).

| Example Implementation |
| --- |

```js
  // Fetching branches...
  const branches = await userClient.paginate(userClient.rest.repos.listBranches, {
    owner: ownerId,
    repo: reposId,
  });

  // Filtering the retrieved branches.
  const prefixedBranches = branches.filter((branch) => branch.name.startsWith(branchPrefix));
  console.log(`${prefixedBranches.length} branches match the filter`);

  // Creating pull requests...
  const result = await Promise.allSettled(
    prefixedBranches.map((branch) => {
      return userClient.rest.pulls.create({
        title: `Fusebit Generated PR from ${branch.name}`,
        head: branch.name,
        base: targetBranch,
        owner: ownerId,
        repo: reposId,
      });
    })
  );
```

| [<kbd>View in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-a672998e4d4640a1/share/share/edit?integrationId=Github-Create-PRs) |
| --- |